# replace multiple sequence of letters from a search keyword at a time

Tags: java, regex, apache-stringutils

I have an ORACLE CONTAINS search like this.

```
WHERE CONTAINS (FIRST_NAME, '%' || 'Müller' || '%')
```

I have a problem in searching inputs that contains strings such as "and", "btg", "sqe", "ntp" etc. I am looking for a way to replace or escape all these special strings at a time, from the key word, rather than using multiple replaceAll or replace.

For example if I have a search input as `Abcdbtgsqe123` I need to input:

```
Abcd\\\\\\\btg\\\\\\\\sqe123
```

so that the CONTAINS works fine.

I have a long list of such inputs, and I would like to know if the best way to replace all at a time.

Thanks

Comment: The term is **stop-words** removal.

Comment: You could do one regex replace with `'(and|btgsqe|...)'` with `%` or so.